# CVXOPT Portfolio Optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, portfolio, cvxopt

When using the CVXOPT quadratic programming solver to optimize a portfolio and maximize volatility (yep maximize not minimize), I receive the error given below. I have played with the optimizer and determined the error is produced by the solver because of "P = -1*covars". I tried to have the optimizer maximize volatility by minimizing its negative value. The error disappears if I replace the line above with "P = covars". Any ideas on how I would maximize volatility?

Context:
bnds is a 1652 by 1 matrix with the upper and lower bounds for 826 stocks
covars is a 826 by 826 co-variance matrix
numAssets is 826

Aim:
I am trying to set up the objective and constraints such that each of the 826 stocks has a weight between the lower and upper bounds (values found consecutively in bnds) and the weights sum to 1.

```
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers, printing, blas
q = matrix(0, (numAssets, 1), 'd')
G = matrix(0, (2*numAssets, numAssets), 'd')
for i in range(numAssets):
     G[2*i,i] = -1
     G[2*i+1,i] = 1
h = bnds
A = matrix(1.0, (1, numAssets), 'd')
b = matrix(1.0)
P = -covars
portfolio = solvers.qp(P = P,q = q, G = G ,h = h ,A = A,b = b)['x']
```

ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n

Comment: You are making the problem non-convex. Cvxopt is for convex problems.

Comment: I guess I would ask how you know it is non-convex now and if there are other optimizers you recommend I use?

Comment: `f = convex <=> -f is concave` is usually mentioned in textbooks. A general purpose NLP solver can find local optima. For proven global solutions you need a global solver. Anyway, finding a solution with maximum risk is not so interesting anyway. I would focus on solutions with minimum risk.

Comment: I have optimized for minimum risk in the past. Thought this would be interesting (while having additional constraints so it would not select the riskiest single stock). I would have assumed that the mechanics that work f if it required convex optimization would also work for -f. Anyway, Thanks! You saved me a ton of time!